# realurl in typo3

Tags: typo3

I'm working on a website that is made in typo3. I'm doing a part of the website that is made by somebody else, so I don't know that much of typo3.

This website uses realurl to translate the url to a readable one. How can I make a realurl? When I make like for example the index page there is no realurl made for this page. How could I generate one?

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, check the manual of realurl :

  http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/realurl/current/
  http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/realurl/1.10.2/view/
- Check if RealUrl is enabled via TypoScript.
- Check if links are generated with TYPO3 API / TypoScript.
- Use RealUrl configurators

  http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/cbrealurl/current/

Comment: @Aaska I know you were just trying to help, but it is considered bad form to keep trying to make the same edit over and over again.  If you feel there is a proper edit that gets rejected (like the link edit you tried to make below), then you should ask for guidance on [Meta](http://Meta.Stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry got more relevant tutorials about RealURL:

- http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2008/05/realurl-made-easy-part-1.html
- http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2008/06/realurl-made-easy-part-2.html

RealURL will be very easy to understand when you'll make it work with default configuration and understand the meaning of parts: 'init', 'preVars', 'postVarSets', 'pagePath', 'fixedPostVars' and 'fileName'.

Answer (score 0):

Copy my configuration
**typoscript in setup:**

```
config.simulateStaticDocuments = 0

config.baseURL = /
config.tx_realurl_enable = 1
config.uniqueLinkVars = 1
config.absRefPrefix = http://www.ceisufro.cl/
page.config.language = cl
config.sys_language_uid= 0
config.useSysLanguageTitle = 1
config.language= es
config.language_alt= es
config.htmlTag_langKey= es
config.linkVars = L
config.sys_language_overlay = 1
config.htmlTag_setParams = xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xml:lang="es" lang="es"*
```

**In file localconf.php**

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
    'www.ceisufro.cl'=> array(
    'init' => array (
            'enableCHashCache' => '1',
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
            'enableUrlDecodeCache' => '1',
            'enableUrlEncodeCache' => '1',
        ),
        'redirects' => array (
        ),
       'preVars' => array(
          '0' => array(
             'GETvar' => 'L',
             'valueMap' => array(
                'es' => '1',
                'en' => '0',
                'it' => '4',
            ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
             'valueDefault' => 'es',
         ),

      ),

       'fileName' => array(
          'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => '1',
      ),

       'pagePath' => array(
          'type' => 'user',
          'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
          'spaceCharacter' => '-',
          'languageGetVar' => 'L',
          'expireDays' => '3',
          'rootpage_id' => '1',
      ), 'fileName' => array (
            'index' => array (
                'rss.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '100',
                        'id' => '37'
                    ),
                ),
                 'contacto.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'id' => '666',
                        'no_cache'=>'1'
                    ),
                ),

                )),
       'fixedPostVars' => array(
      ),

   ),

);
```

**go to ext manager, find the ext realurl and add the following configurations**

check Enable automatic configuration
select Serializable in Automatic configuration file format
check Enable devLog

**I wait to can help somebody**